# What's the difference between Goal_*_nb_* and nb_* statistics in Piwik?

Tags: api, matomo

I'm looking at the `piwik_archive_numeric` table, and as far as I can tell, stats with the name `nb_{actions, uniq_visitors, visits, visits_converted}` seem to be calculated by the VisitsSummary plugin.

But there are very similar statistic names like `Goal_*_nb_{visits_converted, conversions}` which seem to be calculated by the Goals plugin, but they seem related to each other. What's their relationship?